# Cordova - Modify build.gradle after cordova prepare

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I'll try to make this question as clear as possible as my problem and what I want to solve is kind of confusing.

I am creating an `Ionic 3` App, which uses `Cordova`. My problem is that my client makes me stick with `version 7.1.0` of `Cordova`. Using this version causes conflicts with the `Gradle` version and the plugins version as the `Gradle` version `Cordova` is making me stick to is VERSION.

So you might think: Why not just downgrade the plugins version then?  Easy: it brings me even more issues as older versions of the plugins I need to use don't work properly.

So you also might think: Why not just update `Gradle` version then?  Also easy: I have already tried but using a greater version I get other errors. I can correct those errors in `build.gradle` but when I use the command **ionic `Cordova` build android** it'll just undo the corrections I did in `build.gradle` and then I get the errors again.

So as this is also a npm project, I thought: "Oh well, I might be able to set a script in my `package.json` which concatenates **ionic cordova prepare android && 'a script to do the modifications in build.gradle'**. So, if this is the only way to make it work. My question is: **How can I do to modify the `build.gradle` right after it's been created?** I've thought of gulp but I don't really know how to do it.

Anything that can help either a way of updating `Gradle` which I already tried by setting a environment variable with a value to where the `gradle` version I want to use is or making the modification after creating the `build.gradle` would solve this I think.

If you wonder why not just do it manually is because my client wants that only running **ionic cordova build android** does all the work.

If there's any doubt that might help clear this up I'll update this post with an answer to any doubt.

Comment: You say **"Using this version causes conflicts with the Gradle version and the plugins version"** so.... do you want us to resolve these conflicts ? If so then show the errors. This question will get down-voted very fast if you make it clear what you want.

Comment: Hi @JonGoodwin , no, I don't want you to solve those conflicts because as I mentioned I already did that but more conflicts come like plugins not working properly.

What I really want is to know how can I modify files automatically after they've been created through the scripts in package.json